# CAML query logic

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

When I extract data from a list and want to filter them, I use

```
"intraActive eq 1 and StartDate lt datetime'" + new Date().toISOString() + "' and OData__EndDate ge datetime'" + new Date().toISOString() + "'";
```

Full code:

```
var promise = web.getList(listUrl).items;

if (filter) {
    promise = promise.filter(filter); //Filter is the code snippet above
}
```

I now want to use CAML to do the same thing

```
 "<View><Query></Query></View>";
```

However, I have no clue about CAML. Any help?

Comment: what is the type of interaActive?

Comment: As you can see from @GaneshSanap and my answer - the `caml` is simple. :-) You'd need to get the types in order (bool vs. text in the answers) and whether you'd need "only" the dates or  have time included (see `IncludeTimeValue="True"`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like below (Assuming type of `intraActive` field in Yes/No(Boolean)):

```
<And>
    <Eq><FieldRef Name="intraActive" /><Value Type="Boolean">1</Value></Eq>
    <And>
        <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name="OData__EndDate" />
            <Value Type="DateTime">2015-08-15T00:00:00Z</Value>
        </Geq>
        <Lt>
            <FieldRef Name="StartDate" />
            <Value Type="DateTime">2015-08-15T00:00:00Z</Value>
        </Lt>
    </And> 
</And>
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to generate CAML is to use a list view.  Create a list view with EXACTLY how you want items to be returned.  Then go to it with REST

`<site collection url>/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('<list name>')/views/getByTitle('<view name>')`

Then look for the value of `d:ListViewXml`
This will be the exact CAML query for the view you've customized.

Answer (score 1):

probably something along the lines of (*warning: untested*!)

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <And>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="intraActive" />
        <Value Type="Text">1</Value>
      </Eq>
      <And>
        <Lt>
          <FieldRef Name="StartDate" IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" />
          <Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="TRUE">2012-03-14T00:00:00Z</Value>
        </Lt>
        <Ge>
          <FieldRef Name="EndDate" IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" />
          <Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="TRUE">2012-03-14T00:00:00Z</Value>
        </Ge>
      </And>
    </And>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

Be sure to checkout [U2U CAML Query Builder](https://www.u2u.be/software) and if you're bulding the CAML using c# I recommend using [camlex](https://github.com/sadomovalex/camlex)